# Eclipse won't recognize PNG in any drawable folder

Tags: android, eclipse, drawable

I have an android app in Eclipse Kepler that has a background image called TheBackground.png.

I added TheBackground.png to res/drawable-mdpi, and my activity_main.xml starts with:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/TheBackground.png"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

but Eclipse throws this error at the android:background line:

*No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/TheBackground.png')*

I have tried adding TheBackground.png to all of the res/drawable-*dpi folders, and creating a res/drawable folder and adding it there, but it returns the same error.

Note that the filename does point to a valid PNG image.

Am I missing something?

Comment: do a project clean up and try again

Answer (score 4):

Rename your png image file, all chars must be lowercase.

```
 android:background="@drawable/the_background.png"
```

The resource compiler converts directory names to lower case before processing to avoid problems on case-insensitive file systems. Any capitalization in the names is only to benefit readability.

Answer (score 2):

You just don't need ".png" when set drawable. And use lower-case.

```
android:background="@drawable/the_background"
```

Answer (score 1):

change the name of png file to  lower case

Answer (score 0):

Rename your .png file to lower case.

Refresh your eclipse project by right clicking on project then Refresh, or by pressing F5 after clicking on project.

Clean it from `Project->Clean` and then u should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Making it lowercase was half of the solution; apparently, it didn't like the ".png" added to it.  When I changed it to "@drawable/the_background", it compiles successfully.